# Как сверстать мобильную версию так, чтобы при увеличении масштаба некоторые блоки сохраняли размер и оставались неподвижными от прокрутки?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, веб-сайт

Вероятно, глупый вопрос. Я понимаю, что указанная в заголовке проблема легко исправляется средствами JS. Просто отменяем обычный зум, и делаем собственное (кастомное) изменение масштаба для нужных элементов на странице. Наверняка, уже и куча фреймворков реализуют этот функционал. Но мне интересно, можно ли добиться такого через CSS без подключения лишних скриптов?

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
img { display: block; 
      width: 100vw; height: 100vh; 
      object-fit: cover; }
#cross{ position: fixed; 
        width: 3cm; height: 3cm; 
        left: calc(50vw - 1.5cm); top: calc(50vh - 1.5cm); }
```

```html
<!-- фиксированный крест -->
<svg id="cross" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     viewBox="0 0 460 460" style="enable-background:new 0 0 460 460;" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon style="fill:#0B389C;" points="306.5,153.5 306.5,0 230,0 230,460 306.5,460 306.5,306.5 460,306.5 460,153.5  "/>
    <polygon style="fill:#4370D9;" points="153.5,0 153.5,153.5 0,153.5 0,306.5 153.5,306.5 153.5,460 230,460 230,0  "/>
</svg>
<!-- На фоне для примера большая катинка, которую можно увеличить -->
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1636652576067-56f9541f6c57?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=5466&q=80"/>
```

Comment: Если вопрос про нативный жест pinch zoom, меняющий масштаб отображения документа в мобильном браузере, то он действует на все элементы разом.

Вам остается либо самому обрабатывать мультитач-жесты на js, либо после каждого изменения масштаба документа восстанавливать положение/размер элемента относительно вьюпорта (опять js)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Может быть есть какие-то специфичные единицы измерения размеров, независимых от масштаба?